# How many rooks can hide on a chess board with blockers?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, pseudocode

You are given an m * n chessboard (where m≤n≤50 ) with x blocked cells. We know where the blocked cells are and we know the exact location of them.

Your job is to provide the maximum number of Rooks you can put on the chessboard so that no 2 Rooks attack each other.

Any pseudocode or even code in any language would be helpful.

input output sample:

in 3*3 chessboard,

x = 3

blocked Cells:
(0, 0),
(0, 1),
(0, 2)

answer = 2

Comment: This is the n-rooks problem. You will find multiple resources on this online

Comment: @sshashank124 I didn't find it with the blocked cells. I knew how to solve the n-rooks but this one is about graphs.

Comment: @Deduplicator can you add any algorithm or pseudocode for it?

Comment: Here is a partial answer: for a square board each cell is used (n-1)! times in n! ways of placing rooks on an n*n board.  If you block a single cell, there are n-1 other cells in that row that the rook can be placed in which creates a (n-1)*(n-1) sub-chessboard which can now hold n-1 rooks. Therefore you can still place n rooks on the board if you block up to n-1 cells in a row.

Comment: No attempt, no research, no specific problem while trying? Just a dump of the text of a challenge?

Comment: I couldn't find similar problems online, but I tried it on small inputs which I added to the question @trincot

Comment: @BAbali It doesn't work. In the simple example I added, we can't put 3 rooks and the answer is 2.

Comment: @MJane Gotta read carefully what I wrote.  "If you block up to n-1 cells in a row you can still put n rooks on the board".  i.e. if you block n cells in a row (or column), you cannot put n rooks, which is what your example has (n=3).  And you can recursively apply this logic to sub-n size boards created by placing a rook.  Each time you place a rook, it eliminates the row and column that its placed in which creates a "sub-board"

Comment: @BAbali yes now it makes sense. worked on other sample data I tried too. Thanks.
I try to prove it is the right answer.

Comment: @MJane Here is even a simpler answer, again for an n*n chessboard.  Place n rooks on the diagonal. This is one of the n! solutions to an unblocked chessboard. Now arbitrarily call the remaining n*(n-1) cells "blocked."  So the net answer is that as long as you have n-1 or fewer blocked cells in each row, you can place n rooks. However the set of blocked cells in any two rows cannot be in the same positions.  (The fact that the rooks are on a diagonal does not matter. You can permute the columns n! times and they will still be a valid solution)

Comment: @BAbali it could work but the time complexity is high and I have limited amount of run time ,  it should finish before 2s. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a blocker after the last row in each column.
2. Sort the blockers by column first, row second.
3. Add an array with indices of the first blocker in each column.
4. For each row, find the unused column with the nearest blocker per free stretch (any will do if multiple candidates).

   1. Place towers there and mark as used.
   2. Advance all columns where you encountered a block and mark column as usable.

All-in-all, the algorithm should run in O(n * m + x * log(x)).

Comment: what if the first cell of a row is blocked? like in a 3*3 chessboard (0,0), (1,1) , (2,2) the answer should be 3 here but in this algorithm we can have only 2? Should we perform this for start and end of each row?

Comment: @MJane Had a small error, should be fixed.

Comment: so it doesn't matter to chose the unuesd col with nearest block from right or left of the first blocker right?

Comment: Yes, all unused columns are only rated on their first blocker, and are otherwise equal.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on the code now.